# React UseState not updating immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to build a react landing page shows the different screen based on the props.products. If products exists in the API call response, it'll update the global state of products and update products from null to an array. The problem I face here is that even though the state is updated (I've checked through Redux Dev Tools), the pages doesn't show the correct screen. The problem occurs when trying to load screen type 3.

```
function LandingPage(props) {
  const [eligibleProducts, setEligibleProducts] = useState([]);
  const [screenType, setScreenType] = useState();
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isActive, setisActive] = useState(false);

  const { pocBusinessEmail, pocBusinessName } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    handleEligibleProducts();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('count')
    if(props.products && (props.products.filter((product) => product.productStatus === 2).length > 0)){
      console.log("init")
      setisActive(true)
    }
  }, [props.products]);

  useEffect(() => {}, [props.eligibleProducts]);
  

  const handleEligibleProducts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let data = {
      userType: 102,
    };
    data["email"] = window.localStorage.getItem("email");

    try {
      
      const res = await props.getEligibleProducts(data);
      const { statusCode, msgText, productList, Url } = res.data.responsePayload;
      let allEligibilityFlagZero = false;
      let noidforsome = false;
      if (Url.length != "") {
        setUrl(new URL(Url));
      }
     if(statusCode === 200){
          let data = {};
          data["employeeId"] = props.employeeId;
          data["products"] = null;
          await props.employeeProduct(data);
      } 

      if (productList) {
        setEligibleProducts(productList.map((product) => ({ ...product, selected: false })));
        allEligibilityFlagZero = productList.length && productList.every((product) => product.eligibilityFlag === 0);
       // noArcIdForSomeProduct = productList.length && productList.some((product) => !(product && (product.arcId || product.arcId !== null)));
      //  if(props.products){
      //     if((props.products.filter((product) => product.productStatus === 2).length > 0)){
      //       setisActive(true)
      //     }
      //   }
      

      
        }

      if (statusCode !== 200) {
        setScreenType(4);
        setMessage(msgText);
      } else if (!(productList && productList.length !== 0) || allEligibilityFlagZero) {
        setScreenType(1);
      } else if (!isActive) {
        setScreenType(2);
      } else {
        setScreenType(3);
      }
      setLoading(false);
      
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log("big error: " + error);
    }
  };
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const routeChange = (direction) => {
    let path = direction;
    navigate(path);
  };

  const getProperScreen = () => {
    switch (screenType) {
      case 1:
        return <ScreenOne eligibleProducts={eligibleProducts} />;

      case 2:
        return <ScreenTwo eligibleProducts={eligibleProducts} handleSelectProduct={handleSelectProduct} selectUnSelectAllProduct={selectUnSelectAllProduct} />;

      case 3:
        return <ScreenThree eligibleProducts={eligibleProducts} handleSelectProduct={handleSelectProduct} selectUnSelectAllProduct={selectUnSelectAllProduct} products= {props.products} />;

      case 4:
        return <ErrorScreen message={message} />;
      
      default: 
        return <ScreenOne eligibleProducts={eligibleProducts} />;
    }
  };

  if (loading) return <Loader />;

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth={false}>
        <Grid container sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between", p: "1rem 2rem" }}>
          <Grid item>
            <Box>
              <Header registrationBool={true} loggedInBool={true} pocBusinessEmail={pocBusinessEmail} pocBusinessName={pocBusinessName} />
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
      {getProperScreen()}
      {<FooterButtonContainer title="Apply Now" handleApplyNow={handleApplyNow} eligibleProducts={eligibleProducts} />}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default LandingPage;
```

Comment: Are you saying that `getProperScreen()` isn't returning the correct component based on the `screenType` state? How are you verifying that?

Comment: I'm verifying it manually by looking at the screen that is being rendered. The state of isActive also will not change from false to true for some reason

Comment: Try useLayoutEffect() instead of useEffect https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Comment: _"The state of isActive also will not change"_... That's dependent on `props.products`.  Do you see `"init"` logged from your 2nd effect hook?

Comment: @Phil Yes, I do see it

Comment: @lingar I just tried using it instead of the useEffect that sets isActive but it didn't change anything

Comment: @Angela Rubchinsky For better analysis consider using something like `eslint` or provide a code-sandbox so it's easier to debug. It is quite hard to tell just like that.

Comment: Will it ever make it into those other code paths that `setScreenType` 1,2 or 3? You've got a case for a response of `200` and another for if it isn't, so those other branches of your if/else will never be traversed.

Comment: @SuperJumbo I've just updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I'm seeing is that `handleEligibleProducts` depends on `isActive` and `props` but the effect hook that calls it has no dependencies.

It's best not to call functions defined within the component within an effect hook as the dependency graph gets messy. Instead, define the function within the effect hook itself and make sure all dependencies are listed.

```js
const { products, getEligibleProducts, employeeId, employeeProduct } = props;

useEffect(() => {
  const handleEligibleProducts = async () => {
    // ...
  };

  handleEligibleProducts();
}, [
  isActive,
  getEligibleProducts,
  products,
  getEligibleProducts,
  employeeId,
  employeeProduct,
]);
```

[image: Edit cranky-satoshi-se5pws]

As [F.Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294283/f-m%C3%BCller) mentioned, you should ideally use a linter that points out these issues.